# How to check in GCP console, the number of put operations performed while uploading file to GCS bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have uploaded a big file of more than 5 GB size but I want to ckeck this big file is counted as single put operation or it will counted as multiple put operations based on the number of small chunks GCP divided this file.
I am not able to find any such monitoring on GCP console. Kind help/guide me how to check the number of class A or class B operations performed so far in GCP.

Comment: AFAIK there is no method to track put operations per upload.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Is there any provision to check cumulative put operations in Billing resource at the time of billing.

Comment: Export your billing data to BigQuery. You can then query billing details. However, I do not know if put operations are tracked the way you want. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery

Comment: This might help. Thanks!